# Running shiny server app with additional r files

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have 3 files which are needed to my `app`.

First a general `r` with functions make some calculations and need to load the `ui` and `server` files to run the `app`.

When I run it on `Rstudio` it works fine. How is it possible to insert this `app` to `shiny server`, meaning that I need first a script and after that run the `ui` and `server` files?

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson5/ will help you.

Comment: Its been a long time since I used shiny so can't remember exactly but I think you can just C&P the first file (Rstudio running code) into the first lines of the UI file.  Then comes the UI code.  Shiny runs the R code, sets up the variables etc then does the UI.  Quick to try anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `global.R` file or use `source(file, local = FALSE)` to read R Code from a `file`.

For more details check the [scoping rules.](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html)